# Popup for Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to create a popup to change a parameter?  We are dealing very limited space as we are developing a mobile app.

It is a KPI tracker with the ability to see what a users final score will be if they adjust certain areas of the KPIs.

Basically I want to have a screen like this with buttons to change each Parameter- and when they click the button it will pop up a small window where they can adjust the KPI.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: You can create a collapsing menu utilizing layout containers. Check out this blog post. https://www.interworks.com/blog/rrouse/2016/01/04/creating-collapsing-menu-container-tableau

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you embed your dashboard into a web page and then use the Javascript API to do pop ups or any other dynamic interaction you want.

One thing I've started doing is to put my filters and parameters in a horizontal frame just below a dashboard's title. And set the selectors to not be dropdowns. It takes very little vertical space if they are laid out horizontally. Doesn't always work but it might help your situation.

Comment: Thanks Alex,  I believe Bernardo's link will actually accomplish what I am looking for.